# Can I integrate new file types with the Google Drive Viewer?

Tags: google-drive-api

I realize that it's possible to create a *new* viewer for files stored on Google Drive, but is there a way to integrate with the already existing Google Drive Viewer and generate previews for unsupported file types?

I want to embed a Java applet in place of the "No preview available" box. Like:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="XXX" width="XXX">
    <param name="code" value="MyApplet" />
    <param name="archive" value="MyApplet.jar" />
    <param name="driveFile" value="PATH TO FILE" />
</object>
```

Can this be done, or will I have to create an entirely new viewer for something as simple as this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For now you have to create a new viewer for this. In the future we might allow you to upload previews of the file but it will probably just be a static image that we will use for thumbnails and the preview.